# CodeIgniter routes not accepting exceptions different from routing table

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, base-url

somehow I got stuck with my routing rules. I can't set a routing for a page that exceeds the routing rule. For example I have in my **routes.php**:

```
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1/$2/$3';
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1/$2';
```

so the page loads properly with addresses:

- mypage.com/value1/value2/value3/
- mypage.com/value1/value2/

However if a user intentionally enters another value, it will throw a base_url() exception, which is not even handled by my 404 exceptions catch, so I get:

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error
Message: Call to undefined function base_url()
```

I can, of course, create another rule to catch 4th value but then, 5th value will throw that error ;)

What I want to achieve is to find a rule, that will match to ANY tree that exceed last rule, something like:

```
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(no matter the value and tree)'] = 'pages/view/$1/$2/$3';
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1/$2/$3';
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1/$2';
```

So I won't have any errors even if a user type:

- mypage.com/value1/value2/value3/4/5/6/7/8/9//10/11/12/13/14/15/blabla/etc...

I'm sure there is a workaround for this (some regex there? (:any) or :any will not work, it will catch only one tree more), however I didn't found any and I'm aware that solution may be simple, but I didn't mastered CI routing yet...

Thank you in advance for any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a normal regex like so :

```
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1/$2/$3';
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1/$2';
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/.*'] = 'pages/view/$1/$2/$3';
```

The more important question is why doesn't that load a 404? If your custom 404 page is using the `base_url()` function, autoloading the url helper will fix that error.

Comment: Simple as that, adding /.* at the end of the rule solved my issue :) Unfortunately loading the url helper did not work, I've tried that earlier.